# SSRS report while exporting it is giving misterious boarders

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

My [SSRS] report exports to PDF just fine, but when it exports to excel, I end up with these strange and mysterious grids.
[image]

When I checked with the other server it appears to export correctly. There, the extension is .xls, but xlsx. in the strange and msyterious versions.

Is there any difference in these extensions?

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to ask - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and *proof read before posting*. You are worried about "mysterious borders" not "misterious boarders"... which sounds more like pirates

Comment: Are there other elements of the report that we're not seeing?  It looks like this is occurring where there are merged columns, which you can generally avoid generating by working on the design layout.  Other than that, yes, the xls and xlsx extensions are created by different renderers: Excel and ExcelOpenXml, respectively.